# Issues selecting rows that were inserted today in db

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a select of rows that are inserted into the database today.

I tried the following:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `urls` WHERE 'dateurl' = CURRENT_DATE()";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `urls` WHERE 'dateurl' = NOW()";
```

They do not seem to work. The date is stored into the database as TIMESTAMP.

Full code:

```
<?php

$con2 = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `urls` WHERE 'dateurl' = CURRENT_DATE()";

if ($result2 = mysqli_query($con2,$sql2))
{
$rowcount2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
if ($rowcount2 == 0) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><img src="images/check.gif" 
alt="check" class="icon" /> There are no URLs shortened today.</div>';  
} else {
echo '<div class="alert alert-info"><img src="images/check.gif" alt="check" 
class="icon" /> Shortened today: '.$rowcount.' short URLs</div>';
}
mysqli_free_result($result2);
}

mysqli_close($con2);

?>
```

I always get the message: There are no URLs shortened today.

What do I do wrong? Thank you.

Comment: CURRENT_DATE() and now return the complete timestamp you have to search only with date not time

Comment: Also check your quotes - your using single quotes round `'dateurl'` in your SQL - which either should be backticks - or just leave them out altogether.

Comment: Columns should be surrounded by backticks, not single quotes.

Comment: It is not a duplicate since that did not solved the issue. Still not working. I edited to have the backticks.

Comment: Thank you for the hint Omer Muhammad, will check that.